# How do I get a list of our partners?

Tags: partner

I have very little experience with SF so am probably doing something very simple wrong.  All I want is a list of our partners byt type.  I've tried Reports>New Report>Accounts with Partners, set it to All accounts and All Time and there are only 4 results.

I then tried Reports>New Report>Oppertunities with Partners, all oppertunities and all time and this time got 2 results.

I have full admin access if that makes any difference, and am completely stumped.

Thanks,

CLS

Comment: What about query objects `OpportunityPartner`, `AccountPartner`

Answer (score 1):

`Accounts with Partners` will give you a list of all customer accounts that are associated to other accounts via the `Partner Role` relationship. This is not what you want.

In order to just get a list of all Partner Accounts, use Report Type `Accounts` and filter on `Partner Account equals true`

[image]

Comment: Hi Guy, thanks for your response.  If I click Reports > New Report > click the + next to Account & Contacts then click Accounts > Create, then the report generated doesn't have Partner Account on there.

Comment: hmm it is for me (added screen capture ti my answer). Do you have Partner Communities enabled or is there some other kind of partner account your are looking for?

Comment: Hi Guy, I don't know how to upload an image I'm afraid, but if do the steps exactly as above there's no result when I type Partner in the Fields box. Is this Partner Communities something I need to activate?

Comment: What is your definition of a Partner? How do you distinguish a Partner from any other Account? E.g. is there a different Page Layout / RecordType / etc?